# How to select descendants of this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

CODE:

```js
$(this).html("<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>");

$(this "td").each(function(index){  //i want a selector somewhat like this (to select td descendants if this)
  //mycode
});
```

Please suggest a syntactically correct selector

Comment: `$(this).find("td")`

Comment: `$(this "td")` ==>  `$("td", this)`

Comment: [Please read the API before asking these sorts of questions](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Read the API. It wasn't clear enough in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Pass [`this` as second parameter to set the context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

```
$("td",this).each(function(index){  //i want a selector somewhat like this (to select td descendants if this)
  //mycode
});
```

---

Or use **[`$(this).find('td')`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** method, this case yo can get reference back to `$(this)` using **[`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)** method.

```
$(this).find("td").each(function(index){  //i want a selector somewhat like this (to select td descendants if this)
  //mycode
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has quite a few ways to target all of the child elements that appear beneath beneath a specific element via the [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function or by simply using the [context parameter of a normal selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) :

```
// This will use the find() function to find all <td> elements under this element
$(this).find('td').each(function(index){ ... });
// This will do the same thing (selecting all <td> elements with this as the context)
$('td',this).each(function(index){ ... });
```

Comment: is `$(this).find('td').each()` possible?

Comment: Yes, the `find()` function will return a set of elements that match the specified selector. So this would "find" all of the `<td>` elements under `this` and then the `each()` function would iterate through that same set of elements.